# Grouping Rows in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, row, ag-grid

In my table I'm using Grouping Rows, but I need to style the length number of the group, in the example shown the group label is like "+Title grouo (3)".
I need to style the '(3)', puting for example a bootsrap label.

How I can style it?

Answer (score 1):

The ag-grid is quite robust and has great options for customization. I haven't used the enterprise edition so haven't played with the row grouping options as much as I should to answer your question. However here is what I have found.

There is a [cellRenderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/index.php) that you can use if you decide to have a special column for the groups themselves. This cell renderer allows you to customize the html as you like and is an attribute of the columnDefs for the Group column

Alternatively if you choose to have the group use the entire row and not have a separate column for the groups you can use the [groupRowRenderer or groupRowInnerRenderer callback which are attributes of the gridOptions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/index.php).

[Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/example5.html) is an example provided by ag-Grid that uses the groupRowInnerRenderer and seems to be similar to what you are looking for.

Finally, if you are looking for the quickest and simplest option, you could just use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) or normal [DOM lookups](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) to find the class `ag-group-child-count` which will give you an array of span elements that you can manipulate to have the proper Bootstrap style that you want

**TL;DR**

do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ag-group-child-count").add("bootstrap-label")
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer, in my case i think using the quickest way is better but unfortanlly i dont have any classe called "ag-group-child-count".

Comment: It wouldn't be a class that you have created, it's a class that gets created on initialization of the ag-grid. If you take a look at the elements in the developer tools you should see the clas there. I went to [this example from ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/example1.html) and opened the developer console and found the class that was associated with the number you are looking for. I assumed this was the default renderer, but if it isn't you should be able to find the correct class that you need for your use case